# How do you transform asp netcore options before they are accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've got options like this:

```
public class ApplicationSettings
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string PluginFolders { get; set; }
}
```

and services like this:

```
public interface IWildcardResolver
{
    string Resolve(string value);
}


public class WildcardResolver : IWildcardResolver
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public WildcardResolver(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        AddWildcard("%contentRootPath%", _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath);
        AddWildcard("%webRootPath%", _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath);
        AddWildcard("%environment%", _hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName);
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _hardWiredValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public string Resolve(string value)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(value);
        foreach (var pair in _hardWiredValues)
        {
            sb.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public void AddWildcard(string name, string value)
    {
        if (_hardWiredValues.ContainsKey(name))
            throw new Exception($"A value for the wildcard {name} already exists.");

        _hardWiredValues.Add(name, value);
    }
}
```

How can i make sure that before i access those settings through DI with `IOptions<AppSettings>` PluginFolders is translated (because it contains wildcards)? I've tried `IConfigureOptions<AppSettings>` and `IPostConfigureOptions<AppSettings>` but both of them appear to happen at a stage too late. it's like i am missing a IPreConfigureOptions or something.

```
public class PluginManager
{
    private readonly IOptions<ApplicationSettings> _settings;

    public PluginManager(IOptions<ApplicationSettings> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
        // how do i get an instance here which makes sure that the ApplicationSettings.PluginPaths is already manipulated without doing it manually?
    }
}
```

Doing it like this works, but then it feels like i am fighting the framework since i can't use `IOptions<AppSettings>` like everywhere else:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#options-post-configuration-1

Comment: Or even this one which i think more closely matches what you want to do https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-di-services-to-configure-options-1

Answer (score 1):

This looks more along the lines of what you are trying to achieve

```
services.AddOptions<ApplicationSettings>()
    .Configure<IWildcardResolver>((options, wildcardResolver) => {
        options.PluginFolders = wildcardResolver.Resolve(options.PluginFolders);
        //...
    });
```

The above registers an action used to configure a particular type of options. Note: These are run before all .

Reference [Use DI services to configure options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-di-services-to-configure-options-1)

Comment: I originally had this method in place but going that route doesn't work if you are loading configurations from configuration files. Originally with the old call order i assumed that it isn't possible to intercept configuration values - i was wrong obviously

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found it out by digging through some microsoft component sources.

This is the solution:

```
public class ApplicationSettingsSetup : IConfigureOptions<ApplicationSettings>
{
    private readonly IWildcardResolver _wildcardResolver;

    public ApplicationSettingsSetup(IWildcardResolver wildcardResolver)
    {
        _wildcardResolver = wildcardResolver;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Configure(ApplicationSettings options)
    {
        options.PluginFolders = _wildcardResolver.Resolve(options.PluginFolders);
    }
}
```

Registration:

```
services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<ApplicationSettings>, ApplicationSettingsSetup>();
services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
```

Previously i was loading the AppSettings from the Configuration and registering `IConfigurationOptions` afterwards. Somehow i assumed the factory which creates Options would know to call `IConfigureOptions` first before returning the IOptions instance - this is wrong.

Changing the order fixed it.

Comment: Check my provided answer, which is the other suggested approach from the docs